# Shallow copy reference into variable in Perl

Tags: perl, shallow-copy, arrayref

In Perl, you can assign to a variable a reference to another variable, like this:

```
my @array = (1..10);
my $ref = \@array;
```

And, as it is a reference, you can do something like this and both variables will be affected:

```
push @array, 11;
push @$ref, 12;
```

and both variables will contain `1..12`, because they both point to the same space.

Now, I'd like to know if there is any way you can do the same thing, but starting with a ref and later assigning that reference to a plain variable. For example:

```
my $ref = [1..12];
my @array = # something here that makes @array point to the same space $ref contains
```

I know I can just assign it like this:

```
my @array = @$ref;
```

but, that's a copy. If I alter $ref or @array, those will be independent changes.

Is there some way to make @array point to the same variable as $ref?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070342/typeglob-aliases

Comment: Take note of Ikegami's note about the most sensible approach. If you work with nested Perl structures, enough, you'll get used to retrieving it as a ref, instead of copying it to an array variable. It only adds 1-character to type to `$`.

Comment: @Axeman2: Yes, of course. This question was more on the educational spirit. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Four ways:

- `our @array; local *array = $ref;`
- `\my @array = $ref;` (Experimental feature added to 5.22)
- `use Data::Alias; alias my @array = @$ref;`
- Using magic (e.g. `tie my @array, 'Tie::StdArrayX', $ref;`)

But of course, the sensible approach is to do

```
my $array = $ref;
```

and use `@$array` instead of `@array`.

---

Aforementioned Tie::StdArrayX:

```
package Tie::StdArrayX;
use Tie::Array qw( );
our @ISA = 'Tie::StdArray';
sub TIEARRAY { bless $_[1] || [], $_[0] }
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done when the array is a package variable, using typeglobs.

```
my $foo = [7,8,9];
our @bar;
*bar = $foo;
$foo->[1] = 3;
print @bar;     # "739"
```

Lexical variables (i.e. `my @bar`) can't be assigned to with typeglobs, though.
Maybe there is a lexical solution or workaround built around [`PadWalker`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PadWalker).

Comment: Data::Alias, not PadWalker.