# mysterious * in front of nested sub

Tags: perl, typeglob

What is exact function/purpose of * in front of _fact and how it can be equivalently written?

```
sub fact {
   my ($n) = @_;

   local *_fact = sub {
       my ($n, $prod) = @_;
       return $prod if $n == 0;
       return _fact($n-1, $n*$prod);
   };

   return _fact($n, 1);
}

fact($n);
```

Answer (score 11):

Ideally, the author of the function would have liked to use

```
sub fact {
   my ($n) = @_;

   my $_fact; $_fact = sub {
       my ($n, $prod) = @_;
       return $prod if $n == 0;
       return $_fact->($n-1, $n*$prod);
   };

   return $_fact->($n, 1);
}
```

Unfortunately, that has a memory leak. The anon sub has a reference to `$_fact`, which holds a reference to the anonymous sub. `$_fact` would need to be cleared to break the reference on exit.

```
sub fact {
   my ($n) = @_;

   my $_fact;
   $_fact = sub {
       my ($n, $prod) = @_;
       return $prod if $n == 0;
       return $_fact->($n-1, $n*$prod);
   };

   my $rv;
   my $e = eval { $rv = $_fact->($n, 1); 1 } ? undef : ($@ || 'Unknown');
   $_fact = undef;
   die $e if $e
   return $rv;       
}
```

But that's UGLY! One way to avoid the problem is using a [Y combinator](http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_Aristotle/journal/30896.html). A much simpler way to avoid the problem is to store the code reference in a package variable instead of a lexical variable (since only lexical variables are captured by subs). This is what the code you posted does. Keep in mind that

```
*_fact = sub { ...  };
```

is basically a run-time version of

```
sub _fact { ... }
```

Both assign the sub to CODE slot of symbol `_fact`.

That said, 5.16 introduced a better fix:

```
use feature qw( current_sub );

sub fact {
   my ($n) = @_;

   my $_fact = sub {
       my ($n, $prod) = @_;
       return $prod if $n == 0;
       return __SUB__->($n-1, $n*$prod);
   };

   return $_fact->($n, 1);
}
```

Comment: saw Y combinator. clicked +1.

Comment: @ikegami could you explain why the eval portion is necessary? Is it just to prevent a thrown error from allowing memory to leak?

Comment: @Nate Glenn, Gotta break the memory cycle even on error (unless you know the program will exit anyway.) The `eval` is probably not needed here as I don't foresee any run-time error, but I included it because this is obviously a learning exercise. Using recursion for factorial in Perl is insanely wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

Check [typeglob aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070342/typeglob-aliases)

Example above should be written using anonymous subroutine/closure:

```
sub fact {
   my ($n) = @_;

   my $_fact;
   $_fact = sub {
       my ($n, $prod) = @_;
       return $prod if $n == 0;
       return __SUB__->($n-1, $n*$prod);
   };

   return $_fact->($n, 1);
}
```

Comment: "What is exact function/purpose of * in front of _fact?"

Comment: It doesn't leak, but it's a poor solution. It removes the tail recursion which was obviously a guiding factor in the design of the sub. `$n ? $n * fact($n-1) : 1` would have sufficed otherwise. Eliminating tail recursion makes it inefficient everywhere. Changing the outer sub to end with `my $rv = $_fact(...); undef $_fact; $rv` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I went a step further and added an `eval`. It's probably not needed here as I don't foresee any run-time error, but I included it because this is obviously a learning exercise. Using recursion for factorial in Perl is insanely wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a funky attempt at creating a closure by assigning a code reference to the typeglob named `_fact` and then calling it pseudo-recursively. (note: a typeglob is the container for all variables with a particular name).

A virtually equivalent (and much more standard) way to write this would be:

```
sub fact {
   my ($n) = @_;

   my $_fact;

   $fact = sub { .... }; # Assigning code-ref to scalar variable.

   return $_fact->($n, 1); # Note the arrow syntax to deref the code-ref
}
```

...but, as was kindly pointed out, that has a memory leak in it... so, I say just dump the closure altogether and write it like so:

```
sub fact {
   my($n,$prod) = @_;

   return((defined $prod) ? (($n == 0) ? $prod : fact($n-1, $n * $prod)) : fact($n,1));
}
```

*(remember, the only thing worse than infinite recursion is... infinite recursion)*

Comment: @ikegami, actually, this code doesn't have a memory leak.  Instead, `$_fact` is not accessible inside the sub, so it can't be used for recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's so called `typeglob` and is used to create table aliases. See [perldoc reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) for more info .